# Si un campo tiene un valor en especifico no muestra la celda

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta  SQL server y quiero que cuando una celda tengo un valor en especifico de una columna, no muestre la celda  salga la celda la consulta es muy largar y tiene muchas tablas, por este motivo daré un ejemplo:

```
select * from tabla-ejemplo:
```

--Resultado

Color -   animal  -  numero

azul  -   mono  -    48

verde - gato - 49

gris - perro - 85

amarillo -pez - 84

necesito que cuando la columna animal diga perro o numero diga 49
no muestre la celda entera dando como resultado

Color -   animal  -  numero

azul  -   mono  -    48

amarillo -pez - 84

Comment: Agrega la estructura de la tabla y la sentencia que utilizas para sacar la información, para que podamos entender de mejor manera lo que necesitas.

Comment: aja.. y donde queres que no se muestre la celda? porque el problema que describis, no tiene nada que ver con sql, es un problema de donde mostras los datos...

Comment: Yo no suelo dar votos negativos, pero contigo hago una excepcion, te doy -1 pq tu redaccion es pesima y la descripcion de tu problema aun mas pesima, lo que demuestra desinteres de tu parte y vienes aqui a que alguien te resuelva tu tarea, hay q respetar a los miembros de la comunidad

Comment: La consulta es muy largar y no me dejan subirla, lo que quiero es que es un campo tiene un valor en especifico no se muestre la celda o consulta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues en tu ejemplo, basta con decirle

```
WHERE numero <> 49 AND animal <> 'perro'
```

Y ya, esas filas no salen